# PHP - CLI vs cronjob - same script, different results

Tags: php, cron, system, exec, command-line-interface

I have a PHP script that runs perfectly fine on the command line if I simply run it like this `php /path/to/script/script.php`.
if I now schedule this very command in cron using `crontab -e` and the add the line:

```
*/1 * * * * php /path/to/script/script.php 2>&1 >> /var/log/logfile.log
```

it does get executed every minute as expected and all the output gets put into the log file just like running it on the command line. But the some parts of the script just don't seemt o work. those particular parts are lines that are like:

```
system('mkdir /mnt/temp', $retVal);
```

or

```
exec('mkdir /mnt/temp');
```

I have tried every possible thing like running it as root, permissions on all scripts and folders that would be affected, using `/bin/mkdir` instead of `mkdir`. The return value from the system() is 0 for running it on CLI and 1 for the crontab way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if its a temporary folder, why not create it inside /tmp?

Comment: a) sure the same php interpreter is called? The `PATH` variable might be different. And b) this might be a permission problem: sure the script is executed under the same user account? Using the same permissions and umasks?

Comment: Permissions most probably! you run the cron as same user as commandline?

Comment: using `crontab -e -u root` shows the job that i added so I would expect it to run as root

Comment: As @HankyPankyㇱ said, almost certainly a permissions issue.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't solve the CLI vs crontab issue, but the solution that worked for me was to use a bash script inside of cron. And that bash script in turn calls the PHP script. this works like a charm under any of the users that I need to run the script.
So I can't say that it is or isn't a permissions issue.

Thanks for all your comments guys